# multiple nested loops don't work as expected

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

Following situation:

I query the database for entries, for testing purposes limited to 100:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sell FROM products LIMIT 100");
$stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then I go in a while loop, I only can take (and work with) 20 entries per function call, so I fetch 20 to my `$List`:

```
while ($result) {
/...
$List->setSell(array($result[0]['sell'], $result[1]['sell'], $result[2]['sell'], $result[3]['sell'], $result[4]['sell'], $result[5]['sell'], $result[6]['sell'], $result[7]['sell'], $result[8]['sell'], $result[9]['sell'], $result[10]['sell'], $result[11]['sell'], $result[12]['sell'], $result[13]['sell'], $result[14]['sell'], $result[15]['sell'], $result[16]['sell'], $result[17]['sell'], $result[18]['sell'], $result[19]['sell']));
```

Now a function is called which is working with the resultset, and then I delete the 20 entries and reset the array values:

```
for ($x= 0;$x<20;$x++) {
        unset($result[$x]);
        $result = array_values($result);
    }
```

**while loop without comments:**

```
 while ($result) {
    /...
    $List->setSell(array($result[0]['sell'], $result[1]['sell'], $result[2]['sell'], $result[3]['sell'], $result[4]['sell'], $result[5]['sell'], $result[6]['sell'], $result[7]['sell'], $result[8]['sell'], $result[9]['sell'], $result[10]['sell'], $result[11]['sell'], $result[12]['sell'], $result[13]['sell'], $result[14]['sell'], $result[15]['sell'], $result[16]['sell'], $result[17]['sell'], $result[18]['sell'], $result[19]['sell']));

 for ($x= 0;$x<20;$x++) {
            unset($result[$x]);
            $result = array_values($result);
        }
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

It seems like it is partly working, I get the following output when doing a var_dump right before the while closing bracket as shown above.

```
array(80) {...}
array(60) {...}
array(40) {...}
array(20) {...}
```

which is as expected, but after twenty it goes to

```
array(10) {...}
array(5) {...}
array(2) {...}
array(1) {...}
array(0) {...}
```

So I don't understand why I get those 10, 5, 2 and 1 valued arrays and what I'm doing wrong here in general. Can someone assist?

Comment: Quick scan through... perhaps because `array_values()` is renumbering your array?

Comment: Yeah but it's supposed to do that, as I pick the first 20 values of the array and put them to the function handle. Do you think this is the error though? @bishop

Comment: Hmm, is resetting `$result = array_values($result);` 20x every loop really necessary? I'm not a wiz at PHP, but I would probably look at a different way to iterate over all of `$result`'s values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying your array WITHIN the `for()` loop that's deleting entries. Consider what happens with a simple 5-element array:

```
   0 => 10
   1 => 20
   2 => 30
   3 -> 40
   4 -> 50
```

Your for/unset loop kicks in and does `unset(0)`, leaving you with

```
1 => 20
...
4 -> 50
```

You then call `array_values()`, and replace your $result array with the new values-only array, so you end up with

```
0 => 20
1 => 30
2 => 40
3 => 50
```

The loop continues, and now you do `unset(1)`, so you end up with

```
0 => 20
2 => 40
3 => 50
```

and after `array_values()` you get

```
0 => 20
1 => 40
2 => 50
```

Next you do `unset(2)`, and now there's nothing else to change in the array - you're unsetting keys  (`unset(3)`, `unset(4)`) which don't exist, and the leftover values will all have the same keys afterwards.

If you're trying to delete the first 20 entries, then **DON'T** do the `array_values()` call within your loop. It should be

```
for ($x= 0;$x<20;$x++) {
     unset($result[$x]);
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Or you could use `array_splice()` and skip the for/unset stuff entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
for ($x= 0;$x<20;$x++) {
        unset($result[$x]);
        $result = array_values($result);
}
```

try

```
for ($x= 0;$x<20;$x++) {
    array_shift ($result);
}
```